After clearing the file, I cannot save more data
I have a code whose role is to save data to a text file. I also have a function defined to clear the file. Unfortunately, after clearing the file, no more data gets saved. I'm saving the output of iperf.
 def start_client_and_print_results(self):
    '''Start iperf client and print results to console'''

    my_iperf_process = subprocess.Popen([self.initalize_iperf, "-c", self.ip_addr, self.force_flush],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    for line in my_iperf_process.stdout:
        print(line)
        self.starting_index_position += 1
        if (self.starting_index_position > self.start_line_to_write_into_file and self.starting_index_position < self.end_line): 
            self.save_results_to_file_txt(str(line) + "\n")
            self.save_results_to_file_csv(str(line) + "\n")

Function used to save data:
def save_results_to_file_txt(self, output):
    '''Save results to a text file'''
    client_results = open("client_results.txt", "a")
    client_results.write(output)
    client_results.close()

Clear data with:
def clear_file(self):
    clear = open("client_results.txt", "w")
    clear.close()

The above-mentioned functions are used together with the tkinter library, for which I have defined buttons with the appropriate functions.
button_iperf = tk.Button(root, text = "Start iperf client", command = iperfing.start_client_and_print_results)

button_clear = tk.Button(root, text = "Clear", command = iperfing.clear_file)

Any ideas?
I tried using the with statement in the file definition, but it didn't work.
Functions are defined in a class.
class Iperf():
    '''Class to handle iperf client functionality'''
    def __init__(self, initalize_iperf: str, force_flush: str, ip_addr: str, starting_index_position: int, start_line_to_write_into_file: int, end_line: int):
        '''Initialize the iperf client instance'''

        self.initalize_iperf  = initalize_iperf
        self.force_flush = force_flush
        self.ip_addr = ip_addr
        self.starting_index_position = starting_index_position
        self.start_line_to_write_into_file = start_line_to_write_into_file
        self.end_line = end_line

so full code looks like:
class Iperf():
    '''Class to handle iperf client functionality'''
    def __init__(self, initalize_iperf: str, force_flush: str, ip_addr: str, starting_index_position: int, start_line_to_write_into_file: int, end_line: int):
        '''Initialize the iperf client instance'''

        self.initalize_iperf  = initalize_iperf
        self.force_flush = force_flush
        self.ip_addr = ip_addr
        self.starting_index_position = starting_index_position
        self.start_line_to_write_into_file = start_line_to_write_into_file
        self.end_line = end_line

    def start_client_and_print_results(self):
        '''Start iperf client and print results to console'''

        my_iperf_process = subprocess.Popen([self.initalize_iperf, "-c", self.ip_addr, self.force_flush],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        for line in my_iperf_process.stdout:
            print(line)
            self.starting_index_position += 1
            if (self.starting_index_position > self.start_line_to_write_into_file and self.starting_index_position < self.end_line): 
                self.save_results_to_file_txt(str(line) + "\n")
                self.save_results_to_file_csv(str(line) + "\n")

        my_iperf_process.kill()

    def start_server(self):
        '''Start iperf server'''
        my_iperf_process = subprocess.Popen(["iperf3","-s","-B", self.ip_addr, self.force_flush],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    def save_results_to_file_txt(self, output):
        '''Save results to a text file'''
        client_results = open("client_results.txt", "a")
        client_results.write(output)
        client_results.close()

    def clear_file(self):
        clear = open("client_results.txt", "w")
        clear.close()

I use these parameters in the class.
iperf_path = "iperf3"
force_flush = "--forceflush"
ip_addr = ""  # Example IP address
starting_index_position = 0
start_line = 3
end_line = 14


Could you make a testable [mre]? And I don't think iperf needs to be there. Just a tkinter window with those two buttons that periodically writes placeholder text to a file.

Are you seeing the output of print(line)? I can't see any reason why it wouldn't write to the file.

what are the values of self.starting_index_position, self.start_line_to_write_into_file and self.starting_index_position, self.end_line , if (as @Barmar asks - are you seeing output from the print) ... are they the reason nothing is getting saved ?

I added a class that I use at the very end of the post. I hope it's clear now how it looks. Data is displayed with print() after clearing, but it does not write directly to the file. Later, the file is empty.

Now you can also see what values I use in the class.

Ok, I managed to find a workaround that looks like this. I'm not handling file saving through Python but doing it directly from the terminal instead:
class Iperf:
    '''Class to handle iperf client functionality'''
    def __init__(self, initialize_iperf: str, force_flush: str, ip_addr: str, starting_index_position: int, start_line_to_write_into_file: int, end_line: int):
        '''Initialize the iperf client instance'''
        self.initialize_iperf = initialize_iperf
        self.force_flush = force_flush
        self.ip_addr = ip_addr
        self.starting_index_position = starting_index_position
        self.start_line_to_write_into_file = start_line_to_write_into_file
        self.end_line = end_line
        self.my_iperf_process = None  # Hold reference to the subprocess

    def start_client_and_print_results(self):
        '''Start iperf client and print results to console'''
        subprocess.run("iperf3 -c ip-address --forceflush > client_results.txt", shell=True)
        

    def start_server(self):
        '''Start iperf server'''
        my_iperf_process = subprocess.Popen(["iperf3", "-s", "-B", self.ip_addr, self.force_flush], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    def clear_file(self):
        '''Delete file'''
        os.remove("client_results.txt")

# Example usage:
iperf_instance = Iperf("iperf3", "--forceflush", "ip-address", 0, 5, 20)
iperf_instance.start_client_and_print_results()
iperf_instance.clear_file()
iperf_instance.start_client_and_print_results()

So even after deleting the file, I can overwrite it again. Thanks everyone for your time! Maybe we'll find another solution as well
